# how to understand "return *test== ‘\0’;"

Tags: c

There is a code snippet,

```
int matchhere(char *regexp, char  *text)
 {
    /* do sth */
    return    *test== '\0';
 }
```

I do not understand what does

```
return    *test== '\0';
```

mean. Or what it will return?  How does "==" function here?

Comment: `Int` and smart quotes. Did you use Ms Word for this snippet? :-)

Comment: The resulting value from all relational or equality operators is an `int` with a value of either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*test` part reads the first character for the C string (a C string is merely a bunch of characters starting at a given address, and the `*foo` operator looks at that address which happens to contain the first character). By definition, a C string ends with a null byte (`'\0'` or simply `0`).

So this tests whether the first character is the end-of-string character. Or in other words: it tests whether the string is empty. That comparison result (1 if empty, 0 if non-empty) is returned.

Answer (score 3):

compare `*test` to `'\0'`, return 0 if inequal, return 1 if equal.

Comment: @DownVoter: Comments with a reason for downvote are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It fails to compile because "test" is not the same as "text", and because there is no such type `Int` in C.

If the typos were fixed, it'd see whether the first letter of the buffer pointed to by `text` is the NULL character -- i.e. it returns `1` if the buffer is empty, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the character pointed by `text` pointer equals `'\0'` character (string-terminating character).

Answer (score 0):

`*test` means the contents of the `test` pointer, which is a `char`.

`*test == '\0'` just compares that character to the null character.

`return *test == '\0'` means return the result of that comparison.

So basically, if `test` points to a null-character then `matchhere()` will return true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if `*test` is an empty string, in that case return a different from zero value

Answer (score 0):

`*test` represents the first character of a string.

`==` is the equality operator.

`'\0'` is the null character, which in C represents the end of a string.

`*test== ‘\0’` is a logical expression which returns true whenever the string is empty.

The whole instruction returns that logical result to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
return *text == '\0';
```

is equivalent to

```
return text[0] == '\0';
```

which is also equivalent to

```
return text[0] == 0;
```

In each case, it's comparing the first character of the string pointed to by `text` to 0, which is the string terminator, and returning the result of the comparison.  It's equivalent to writing

```
if (*text == '\0') // or *text == 0, or text[0] == 0, or !*text, or !text[0]
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
```

Another equivalent would be

```
return !*text; // or !text[0]
```

which will return 0 if `*text` is non-zero, 1 otherwise, but that's pushing the bounds of good taste.